# iOS - tableView's reloadData not call cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, arrays, tableview, reloaddata, uitableview

I don't have any problem with method `cellForRowAtIndexPath` not being called since everything works perfectly.

But here is the situation, I load data from webservice 10 items at the beginning, and add 10 more each times and insert them at the beginning of the array. So the data array has been updated correctly, then I call `[tableView reloadData]`, I also get correct data displayed in `tableView`.

But it's weird that no matter how many items I load more, `cellForRowAtIndexPath` only called 1 time for the first 10 items, it doesnt need to be called again for following 10 items. Why is it so?

Comment: is your number of cells in section method also being updated?

Comment: As I already said, everything is perfect !! But I am only wondering why it is happening that way.

Comment: if everything is perfect, then your app must run well. if doesn't, then something is wrong. can you show the code please ?

Answer (score 0):

It only refreshes the cells it actually needs to draw, it won't call for the others until you are about to scroll them onto the screen. Imagine if you had 1000 cells rather than 20...